# mySQL stored procedure return all rows multiple constraints

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

**Example Scenario:**

Three tables: Employee, Employer, Vertical Market

Employee (employee):

```
| id  | fname | lname | employerid| 
-----------------------------------
| 108 | John  |  Doe  |    12     | 
| 221 | Jane  |  Doe  |    12     |
| 286 | Rob   | Smith |    43     |
```

Employer (employer):

```
| id | name     | vmarketid|
----------------------------
| 12 | Lowes    |  1       |
| 15 | Target   |  1       |
| 43 | Chase    |  2       |
```

Vertical Market (vmarket):

```
| id | name        |
--------------------
| 1  | retail      |
| 2  | banking     |
| 3  | healthcare  |
```

I'm working on a a set of queries to use with a web based reporting front end. The first query will populate a dropdown for Vertical Market and adds an 'All' option at position 0:

```
select 0, 'All'
union
select `id`, `name` from vmarket
```

The second menu is populated via a stored procedure that selects all possible employers for the market type, based on the selection from the first menu (also adding 'All' at position 0):

```
CREATE DEFINER=`reports`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_MarketEmployerSearch`(
market_id INT
)  
BEGIN

SELECT 0, 'All'
UNION
SELECT `id`, `name`
FROM employer
WHERE `vmarketid` = market_id;

END$$
```

The third query is where my question and objective come in. I have another procedure that I would like to return Employee information based off the two selections, be it All/All or Retail/Lowes. Obviously selecting based off two explicitly defined values is easy enough, but what can I do with the query/conditions to allow all rows to return if the user selects All/All?

Here is the obvious syntax for returning the results if someone picks Retail/Lowes from the menus:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`reports`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_EmployeeInfo`(
market_id INT
employer_id INT
)  
BEGIN
SELECT employee.`lname` AS `Employee Last Name`,
     employee.`fname` AS `Employee First Name`,
     employer.`name` AS `Employer Name`,
     vmarket.`name` AS `Market Name`
FROM employee 
   LEFT JOIN employer ON employee.`employerid` = employer.`id` 
   LEFT JOIN vmarket ON employer.`vmarketid` = vmarket.`id` 
WHERE vmarket.`id` = market_id AND employer.`id` = employer_id
ORDER BY vmarket.`name`,employer.`name`,employee.`lname`;

END$$
```

The only thing that comes to mind for dynamically returning 'All' records for an entire vertical market or even for all markets/all employers is some sort of CASE in the WHERE clause but I know that isn't the solution. If that isn't the answer, what options do I have for returning, say, all employees that work in retail, regardless of the store (where the the vmarketid would be 1 based on the first menu and employerid would be 0, returning all employers, based on the second menu).

Any assistance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand what is your target, this solution work for me:

```
SELECT employee.lname AS [Employee Last Name],
 employee.fname AS [Employee First Name],
 employer.name AS [Employer Name],
 vmarket.name AS [Market Name] 
FROM employee 
LEFT JOIN employer ON employee.employerid = employer.id 
LEFT JOIN vmarket ON employer.vmarketid = vmarket.id 
WHERE (vmarket.id = market_id OR market_id=0) AND (employer.id = employer_id OR employer_id=0)
ORDER BY vmarket.name,employer.name,employee.lname;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! I had tried something like this but I was doing it wrong. Rather than parameter=0, I was putting in actualvalue=0, like: WHERE (vmarket.id = market_id OR vmarket.id=0) AND (employer.id = employer_id OR employer.id=0). Thanks so much for spelling it out for me.